# printing list and variable names in triple nested for loop in R does not behave as expected

Tags: r, dataframe, list, for-loop, nested

I'm trying to use a triple nested `for loop` to:

1. loop over a list of dataframes
2. for each dataframe, loop over the each unique value in the "treatment" column
3. for each unique treatment value, perform a statistical test (`shapiro.test`) on the 4 possible variables ("QY_max","FvFo","NPQ_Lss","QY_Lss") of the dataframe.

Therefore, I've written following function:

```
treatment_normality<-function(df_list){
  
  for (df in df_list){
    
    #df.name <- deparse(substitute(df))
    #print(df.name)
    
      for (treat in unique(df$treatment)){
       print(treat)
       df_treat<-dplyr::filter(df, treatment %in% treat)

        for (parameter in c("QY_max","FvFo","NPQ_Lss","QY_Lss"))
          print(parameter)
          print(shapiro.test(df_treat[[parameter]]))
          
      }
  }
  
}
```

I regularly print the variables here to know where I'm at in the `for loop` when I check the output. However, I'm experiencing several issues which I cannot fix. My results look like:

```
[1] "A"
[1] "QY_max"
[1] "FvFo"
[1] "NPQ_Lss"
[1] "QY_Lss"

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  df_treat[[parameter]]
W = 0.94347, p-value = 0.5415

[1] "B"
[1] "QY_max"
[1] "FvFo"
[1] "NPQ_Lss"
[1] "QY_Lss"

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  df_treat[[parameter]]
W = 0.93471, p-value = 0.5065

[1] "C"
[1] "QY_max"
[1] "FvFo"
[1] "NPQ_Lss"
[1] "QY_Lss"
```

I cannot figure out why this for loop does not print my treatment (`print(treat)`), then print the parameter (`print(parameter)`) and then the test output (`print(shapiro...)`). Why does it print all parameters after one another? And why does it show `data: df[[parameter]]` and not the name of my name of my dataframe + variable name e.g. df1[["QY_max"]]? I'd also like to print NAME of the dataframe which is being used with `df.name <- deparse(substitute(df))` and then `print(df.name)`, which should do the trick, but messes up all the results (therefore commented out).

Any idea how can I fix these issues?

Below, you can find a MRE (ChatGPT):

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create a list to store dataframes
list_of_dataframes <- list()

# Define treatments and levels
treatments <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
num_levels <- length(treatments)

# Number of rows in each dataframe
num_rows <- 3 * num_levels

# Generate data for each dataframe
for (i in 1:3) {
  treatment <- rep(treatments, each = 3)  # Each treatment has 2 occurrences
  QY_max <- runif(num_rows, min = 0, max = 100)  # Random QY_max values
  FvFo <- runif(num_rows, min = 0, max = 1)  # Random FvFo values
  NPQ_Lss <- runif(num_rows, min = 0, max = 2)  # Random NPQ_Lss values
  QY_Lss <- runif(num_rows, min = 0, max = 1)  # Random QY_Lss values
  
  # Create dataframe
  df_name <- paste0("df", i)
  list_of_dataframes[[df_name]] <- data.frame(treatment, QY_max, FvFo, NPQ_Lss, QY_Lss)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are not using `treat` in subseting the dataset. You will have the same results

Comment: `shapiro.test(list_of_dataframes$df1$QY_max)` is what your code is doing

Comment: @Onyambu thanks for pointing that out, let say it was friday afternoon... I now added the subsetting of ```treat```. However, the issue of the ```parameter``` remains. Why does it only do ```QY_max```? And ```print(parameter)``` results in all strings of c("QY_max",....) being printed. Why is this the case?

Comment: i do not understand your question, but you should consider looping through the variables first

Comment: @Onyambu sorry if I was unclear. What I mean is that I would expect the following order of output for each of the dataframes: 1) one treatment name (A,B,C,D,orE), 2) one variable name (QY_max,FvFo,NPQ_Lss,QY_Lss, 3) output of ```shapiro.test()``` for that treatment and variable. However, now I get 1) one treatment name 2) ALL variable names, 3) ```shapiro.test()``` output for that treatment and I guess QY_max (see results above). Why does it print ALL variable names after another and print the output of ```shaprio.test``` for only 1 variable?

Comment: Chatgpt to the rescue: I forget a ```{``` at the last for loop...